# Locking global array in a reentrancy-desired function in a multithreaded program?

Tags: c, arrays, multithreading, locking, reentrancy

Sorry if a question title is confusing. I just wanted to put all the things together.
I have a piece of code like:

```
int newThread(int(*pfunc)())
{
   pthread_t tid;
   pthread_create(&tid, NULL, pfunc, NULL);
   int i = 0;
   while(threads[i] != 0 && i < MAX_NUM_THREADS)
   {
      if ((MAX_NUM_THREADS - 1) == i)
      {
        puts("We've run out of threads' number limit\n");
        return 1;
      }
      ++i;
   } 
   threads[i] = tid;
   pthread_join(tid, NULL);
   return 0;
}
```

threads[] is a global array. I want to make this function reentrant, but this means I shouldn't use global variables as far as I understand. I guess that's because values of global variables can be unpredictable at a certain time. But in my case the array seems to be quite predictable.

1. Is it ok, if I lock array with a mutex to make this function reentrant?
2. If yes, then how do I do it right? Just lock the first element before using it and unlock after? or is it better to lock/unlock every element while accessing it?
3. Is this even possible to make this function reentrant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*To say a function is **reentrant**, it should only rely on local variables to be simultaneously called by two (or more threads) and return correct results.*

*If the function rely on some shared data, (we can't really made it reentrant), we can make it **thread-safe** to be called simultaneously by two (or more) threads if all access to the shared data is serialized.*

To make your function thread-safe, you should lock the loop and the insertion into `threads[]`. If you lock only the loop part, somebody could modify the content of `threads` between the end of the loop and the affectation at rank `i`.

```
pthread_mutex_t mymutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

int newThread(int(*pfunc)())
{
   pthread_t tid;
   pthread_create(&tid, NULL, pfunc, NULL);
   int i = 0;
   pthread_mutex_lock(&mymutex);          // take the lock
   while(threads[i] != 0 && i < MAX_NUM_THREADS)
   {
      if ((MAX_NUM_THREADS - 1) == i)
      {
        puts("We've run out of threads' number limit\n");
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mymutex);   // don't forget to release the lock here too :)
        return 1;
      }
      ++i;
   } 
   threads[i] = tid;
   pthread_mutex_unlock(&mymutex);        // release the lock
   pthread_join(tid, NULL);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Julien thank you for edits and answer. That's an idea I had, but I was unsure as I couldn't find any info on that. And I forgot to release lock when returning 1. +1 for that!
I'll take one day to get any more comments if any

Comment: Keep in mind that you'll have to do the same locking everywhere else there's code that touches `threads` as well.